# Where can I find the latest version of yuicompressor to download

Tags: yui-compressor

According to several pages on the internet, the yuicompressor download should be here

http://yuilibrary.com/download/#yuicompressor

But I can't find it on that page.  I tried downloading the some of the other stuff to see if it was embedded within it, but couldn't find it.

I found the github page https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor but there is a comment there that the .jar file was removed from the repo about a month ago.  I am not sure I have enough of the toolchain set up to try and build it from source.

Anyone any idea where I can get the latest .jar
(I DO have yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar but that is quite old now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is here seaching for it:
https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/downloads (the jar is on the *build* folder)

Answer (score 2):

One of the options available is to build the jar file yourself using ant. It should be pretty straightforward as

1. Downloading the source from
   https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/archive/master.zip
2. Downloading and installing [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)
3. "cd"ing to the extracted root directory and typing "ant"

Comment: It's a shame that this tool is outdated :(